# How would I omit zero value decimals in a number format using Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, decimal, decimalformat

I want to drop the decimal digits that are meaningless, like this:

```
14.50   => 14.5
14.0500 => 14.05
14.000  => 14
```

I was searching about how to do that, and I found the following way:

```
{{ number|trim('0')|trim('.') }}
```

But the only problem with the above filter is the following case:

```
0.023 => 023
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention it anywhere, but I assume your "number" variables are actually strings, otherwise the default behaviour would be actually what you're expecting...

My suggestion is simply to cast those `string` variables into `float` variables somewhere in your PHP code, and Twig will render them as you'd expect.

That said, if you *really* need to do that in Twig, you can automatically cast your strings to numbers by performing any arithmetic operations on them. See the following example:

```
{% set stringNumber = '14.0500' %}
{% set number = 14.0500 %}

{{ stringNumber }}      {# Prints 14.0500 #}
{{ number }}            {# Prints 14.05 #}
{{ stringNumber + 0 }}  {# Prints 14.05 #}
```

Full example here: https://twigfiddle.com/hwl82b